# issue with coverity on a shared library

Tags: c++, static-analysis, coverity

I’m facing an issue with coverity on my project. Actually, I have a very big project and I’m using openssl as a shared library beside many other ones. Inside my build directory I have many libraries generated at the compilation of the project.
My problem is when I launch the analysis of my code, it discovers only defects relative to openssl and none of them concerns the code we’re writing.
To build and analyze my project, I used the following commands:

```
cov-configure --template --config configs/config.xml –gcc
cov-build --dir cov_tmp –config configs/config.xml make -j4
cov-analyze --dir cov_tmp
```

To check whether the Coverity analyzes my code or not, I executed the following command:

```
cov-manage-emit --dir cov_tmp --tus-per-psf=all list
```

Unfortunately the analyzed files concerns only openssl.
My question is: can the dynamic linking of my project influence in somehow the result I obtain? And is there any solution to my issue?